# I can't install the software I want to!

Tags: installation

Please help, I cannot install any software. If I try to install google chrome, this what I get

```
sthabiso@sthabiso-R519-R719:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libnspr4-0d libxss1[sudo] password for sthabiso: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libxss1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libnspr4-0d is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libnspr4

E: Package 'libnspr4-0d' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libxss1' has no installation candidate

sthabiso@sthabiso-R519-R719:~$
```

If I install light spark, I get the following

```
sthabiso@sthabiso-R519-R719:~$ sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
[sudo] password for sthabiso: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package browser-plugin-lightspark is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package lightspark is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lightspark' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'browser-plugin-lightspark' has no installation candidate
```

If I install Gnash

```
sthabiso@sthabiso-R519-R719:~$ sudo apt-get install gnash mozilla-plugin-gnash
[sudo] password for sthabiso: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnash is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package mozilla-plugin-gnash is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnash' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mozilla-plugin-gnash' has no installation candidate
```

I cannot do anything,Please help me.

Comment: Google Chrome is not in the software sources so of course you can't install it! If the program isn't in the software sources then the installer wont find them and this will happen!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the following software sources:

1. in "Ubuntu Software" tab:

   - main
   - universe
   - restricted
   - multiverse
2. in "Other software" tab:

   - Canonical partner (both binary and source);
   - independent (both binary and source).

Once you've done all this, open a Terminal window with CTRL-ALT-T and give the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get update -y
```

Now you should be able to install your desired software.

Comment: I have tryed what you told me to do, It doesnt work. It give me the following message

Comment: What is the "ubuntu software" tab? Is there a non-gui way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your /etc/apt/sources.list file had something bad happen to it. I just had a similar problem. I had a fresh sources.list file lying around so I just copied that in place. There is a similar question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140119/every-package-has-no-installation-candidate. You could try using [RepoGen](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) like they suggest.