# Can not Install `banshee-extension-lyrics`

Tags: banshee

I am trying to install `banshee-extension-lyrics` extension. By `sudo apt-get install banshee-extension-lyrics`. But the I got this error as below.

```
rashed@rashed-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install banshee-extension-lyrics
[sudo] password for rashed: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package banshee-extension-lyrics is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'banshee-extension-lyrics' has no installation candidate
```

I tried [I can't install the software I want to!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250829/i-cant-install-the-software-i-want-to/250834#250834) but I got same error. What should I do now, Please help.

Answer (score 3):

*banshee-extension-lyrics* is [not available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/banshee-extension-lyrics) in Ubuntu 14.04. See [bug #1268331](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee-community-extensions/+bug/1268331) - *"banshee-community-extensions demoted to -proposed, not ready for gtk3"*

Comment: Can you suggest any solution to solve this problem..

Comment: Someone has to port it to gtk3. If you are not a developer, then you will have to wait for someone else to do the work.

Comment: is there a way to attract developer attention on this matter??

Comment: The banshee developers have a mailing list http://banshee.fm/about/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Check this script [secLyricsForBanshee.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secLyricsForBanshee.sh), it is on the extras package that can be found at [ScriptEchoColor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/?).

Basically it shows the currently playing music lyrics on terminal, or with `evince` thru a temporary generated pdf file.

It also auto downloads the lyrics if they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `Amarok` in ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. It can fetch lyric for music just fine. I know this is not the perfect solution, but until they fix the problem with `banshee-extension-lyrics` I am using `Amarok` as alternative.
[image]

Comment: Can Amarok integrate the lyrics into the tags as the banshee lyrics extension does?

Comment: do you mean, is amarok can automatically fetch the lyrics from internet??

Comment: No, I mean if Amarok can integrate the lyrics into the music file as metadata. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis_comment

Comment: Sorry I do not have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the "old" package still works with Ubuntu 14.04 despite of error messages. However, having it installed, it "blocks" any updates until the lyrics extension is uninstalled again. That is not a desirable situation, so I have to following workaround:
1) install the "old" extension
2) start banshee (with the extension enabled)
3) uninstall the extension; banshee continues to work with the extension until you restart it

I automated this with the following script (start_banshee.sh):

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo dpkg --install ~/Downloads/banshee-extension-lyrics_2.4.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb
banshee > /dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 20
echo Y | sudo apt-get -f install
```